# Find all characters with "[string]" and make it into an array of data

Tags: php, regex, string

I have some of this text value like

```
$str = 'A quick [color] [animal] [action] over the lazy dog.';
```

I want to find all the data with this "[" and "]" so if I have a long text ill just do `[phone_number]` or something. Can I achieve this into an array value?

My wanted output:

```
$array = ('[color]','[animal]','[action]');
```

cause I will use this later on for `str_replace()`. Is there anyway to do this?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use `preg_match_all`:

```
$str = "A quick [color] [animal] [action] over the lazy dog.";
preg_match_all("/\[[^\]]*\]/", $str, $matches);
echo json_encode($matches); // [["[color]","[animal]","[action]"]]
```

Comment: this actually works! Thanks!

Comment: what about if I do `_this_` instead of `[this]` ?

Comment: In that case, use `preg_match_all("/\_[^\]]*\_/", $text, $match);`

Comment: why do I also get the data with \ in them too?